# Парсинг нестандартного текста

Tags: парсер, текст

В таблице mySQL есть большое количество названий месторождений
Нужно написать программу которая будет разбирать данные названия на [название месторождения][номер куста][номер скважины], если номер куста отсутствует, например: "Солнечный ЛУ, 307", то номер куста остаётся пустым

Пример входных данных:

*Ватьеганское к. 21, 525* вывод: [Ватьеганское][21][525]

*Им. Черномырдина 21, 58* вывод: [Им. Черномырдина] [21] [58]

*Казанская, 2* вывод: [Казанская] [] [2]

*Уренгойское U12, U1207* вывод: [Уренгойское][U12][U1207]

На данный момент решение выполнено с помощью регулярных выражений, но подходит только для шаблона "Месторождение к. 1, 1"

Я писала на python, но можете подсказывать на любом ЯП

Код:

```
            field = re.search(r"^.*?(?=,|к\.)", results['f20020'])
            cluster = re.search(r"\w*?\d.*?(?=\,)", results['f20020'])
            well = re.search(r"(?!.*?,)(?!.*?,)(\S.*)", results['f20020'])
            if field == None or cluster == None or well == None:
                continue
            WELLS[results['f20060']].update(
                {results['id']:
                    {
                        'field' : field.group(0).strip(),
                        'cluster' : cluster.group(0),
                        'well' : well.group(0),
                        'well_name' :results['f20020'],
                        'subsoil_user' :results['f435']
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Ну покажите ваше текущее решение, чтобы было отчего отталкиваться

Comment: Тогда, наверное, можно добавить Уренгойское № U12, № U1207 - № U1209?

Comment: Дело в том, что буква может быть любая(Ватьеганское 41, 4127Г), также перед номером скважины может быть слово "скв.". Все значения берутся из БД, там формат названий никак не регламентирован, много разных вариантов. Даже таких: КГКМ 2; ЛЕДОВАЯ СКВ.5

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
import re

strs = ['Солнечный ЛУ, 307', 'Ватьеганское к. 21, 525', 'Им. Черномырдина 21, 58',
        'Казанская, U2', 'Уренгойское U12, U1207']


for s in strs:
    # если номера начинаются с U, то сначала ее убираем, а затем восстанавливаем.
    u = ''
    if s.find('U') != -1:
        u = 'U'
        s = s.replace('U', '')

    # разбиваем строку на не цифровые элементы, берем первый и удаляем с конца строки все ненужное

    name = re.findall(r'\D+', s)[0].rstrip(' ,')
    name = name.replace(' к.', '')

    # разбиваем строку на цифровые элементы, если один, то добавляем [] и собираем полученное

    nums = re.findall(r'\d+', s)
    if len(nums) == 1:
        ss = [name], [], [f'{u}{x}' for x in nums]
    else:
        ss = [name], *[[f'{u}{x}'] for x in nums]
    print(ss)
```

```
(['Солнечный ЛУ'], [], ['307'])
(['Ватьеганское'], ['21'], ['525'])
(['Им. Черномырдина'], ['21'], ['58'])
(['Казанская'], [], ['U2'])
(['Уренгойское'], ['U12'], ['U1207'])
```